# Selenium driver crashed and gives NoSuchSessionException while using Docker slaves in jenkins

Tags: java, linux, selenium, docker, jenkins

I am using Docker slaves with jenkins and running Selenium tests with jenkins. I'm getting `NoSuchSessionException` which start after driver get crashed.

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: no such session
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461571
(8a88bbe0775e2a23afda0ceaf2ef7ee74e822cc5),platform=Linux 
4.4.0-72-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 4 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.3.1', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10
09:04:52 -0800', ip: '127.0.1.1',
os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0- 72-generic',
java.version: '1.8.0_121' Driver info:
org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver Capabilities [{message=unknown
error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally (Driver info:
chromedriver=2.29.461571
(8a88bbe0775e2a23afda0ceaf2ef7ee74e822cc5),platform=Linux 
4.4.0-72-generic x86_64), platform=ANY}] Session ID: 322db879fc80f5e9d8a7a3b77df7e52f at
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at
 sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at
 sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) at
 org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
 at
 org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
 at
 org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:638)
 at
 org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:661)
```

The tests runs perfectly on local linux system.
As I am using Jenkins pipeline, so tests runs on slaves and for Slave here is little info:

> ARG JENKINS_SWARM_VERSION=3.3 ARG NODE_VERSION=6.10.0
>
> ARG CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION=2.29 ARG GECKODRIVER_VERSION=0.16.1
>
> ENV JENKINS_DATA /var/lib/jenkins ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL info
>
> ## Display options ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive ENV DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN true
>
> ENV SCREEN_WIDTH 1360 ENV SCREEN_HEIGHT 1020 ENV SCREEN_DEPTH 24 ENV
>   DISPLAY :99.0
>   RUN mkdir -p /opt/chromedriver-$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION \   && curl -sS
>   -o /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip
>   \   && unzip -qq /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip -d
>   /opt/chromedriver-$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION \   && rm
>   /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip \   && chmod +x
>   /opt/chromedriver-$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver \   && ln -fs
>   /opt/chromedriver-$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver
>   /usr/local/bin/chromedriver

I also use export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=/dev/null. shm in Docker is nearly 1.0G.
Still unable to trace info.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. 
1. Problem: Chrome and its sandbox
As we know wrapped Chrome all "tabs" in a sandbox with its own process and so. What I did not know is that Chrome uses unix virtualization tools. Tools that are not allowed inside a docker container.
The "simple" solution would start the container with -priviledged, which is of course unsuitable, or assign the container the capability "SYS_ADMIN" - equally unpleasant.
What I have done now in the Webtest driver Factory the Chrome the sandboxen to get used to:

**String [] args = {"--no-sandbox"};
chromeOptions.put ( "args" args);**

So the chrome starts then at least one μ more.
2. The next problem is the missing X server in the host host. To do this, you have to use a screenbuffer in some form, because the Chrome must connect with a display.
You can probably also connect the dockercontainer with the display of the dockerhost using xhost local: root etc. but I did not get to run.
Selenium does this in its NodeBase by wrapping it with the xvfb (virtual framebuffe).

```
> Xvfb-run -n $ SERVERNUM --server -args = "- screen 0 $ GEOMETRY -ac + extension RANDR"   Java $ {JAVA_OPTS} -jar /opt/selenium/selenium-server-standalone.jar \
>     -role node \
>     -hub http: // $ HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR: $ HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT / grid / register \
>     -nodeConfig /opt/selenium/config.json \
>     $ {SE_OPTS} & NODE_PID = $!
```

I had tried initially synonymous, but this does not work, since we only register the swarm client and the ./gradlew tests was not called inside the wrapper. Or I'm too stupid to get that.

Anyways, I solved the now using Jenkins plugin, which is much more beautiful and works with pipelines. In this case, you simply wrapper the commands with the framebuffer within a node:

```
> Node ("webtest") {
>         Wrap ([$ class: 'Xvfb', autoDisplayName: true, 'timeout': 60]) {
>             WithEnv (['DISPLAY =: 0']) {
>                 Echo "Selenium: cluster $ {cluster} - mandantor $ {mandantor} - device $ {device}"
>                 Script {
>                               process = process + "Test Suite"
>                               Def testSuite = config ['mandantor'] [mandantor] [process]
>                               Def specificPropertiesFilename = cluster + '.' + Config ['mandantor'] [mandantor] ['domain'] + '.
>     
>                               cleanupWorkspace ()
>                               CheckoutWebTest (svnUser, svnPassword, mandantor)
>                               GradleSeleniumTest (mandantor, device, testSuite, specificPropertiesFilename)
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
```

Theoretically, you can also mount a framebuffer in the build environment to all nodes that are linked to a specific label (here "webtest"), but this is only for freestyle projects and not for pipeline jobs - because you do not have a build environment. Therefore, the "autoDisplayName" must be set here so that it knows which instance of the framebuffer it should take. Of course, you can wrap the pipeline job in a freestyle, but then it does not work anymore with the parameters from the Jenkins file.